# Template Specialization and std::map

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to create map of `Code` with it's corresponding text and call function. I'm getting compile error and I can't figure out what is wrong with my code, `std::map` initialization. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

namespace mvs
{
    enum Code
    {
        Code0  = -1,
        Code1  = -2,
        Code2  = 1,

        CodeCount
    };
}

class CompositeFile
{
public:
    CompositeFile(std::string const& name) : name_(name) {}

    template <typename T>
    long readEx(mvs::Code code, std::vector<T>& buffer)
    {
         return 0;
    }

    std::string readString(mvs::Code code)
    {
        return {};
    }

private:
    std::string name_;
};

namespace mh
{
     class CompositeFileEx : public CompositeFile
     {
     public:
        CompositeFileEx(std::string const& name) : CompositeFile(name) {}

        template <typename T>
        std::string get(mvs::Code code)
        {
            std::vector<T> buffer;
            readEx(code, buffer);

            return {};
        }

    private:
        typedef std::pair<std::string, std::function<std::string(mvs::Code)> > pair_type;
         **std::map<mvs::Code, pair_type> map_ =
         {
             { mvs::Code1, { "Code1", get<char>(mvs::Code1) } }
         };**
     };

     template <>
     std::string CompositeFileEx::get<char>(mvs::Code code)
     {
         return readString( code );
     }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should define how map is ordered, or in other words, how `mvs::Code` can compare to each other with a functor/lambda. This is because `std::map` uses an ordered list. An alternative is to use `std::unordered_map`, but then you have to provide how to hash your `mvs::Code` with a functor/lambda.

Comment: `**std::map<mvs::Code, pair_type> map_ = ...` this is not a valid syntax.

Comment: @Jaa-c I think he's using that to show where the error is.

Comment: You have at least 2 errors. `{ "Code1", get<char>(mvs::Code1) }` calls the function and returns string, you want to pass a function, so you can for example wrap the call in a lambda. Second, your `CompositeFileEx::get<char>` specialization appears after instantiation.

Comment: @Jaa-c Do you know by any chance how to fix the error of specialization after instantiation?

Comment: @Orion: Well, put the specialization before the instantiation :) If your real code is split between header and cpp file, you can put it to the beginning of the cpp file. If not, you will have to split declaration and definition or forward declare the definition and put the specialization after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look carefully how your pair is defined:

```
std::pair<std::string, std::function<std::string(mvs::Code)>>
```

The second element is `std::function<std::string(mvs::Code)>`. You should send a callable object as the second parameter of your pair when constructing it.

The type of the expression `get<char>(mvs::Code1)` is not a callable object that takes a code as parameter and return a string. The expression result in a string directly.

To solve this, you should send a lambda function that takes a code as parameter, and return the result of `get`

Comment: Thanks for your help, that fixed the error on `map` creation. Now I'm getting error on `template` specialization and I was wondering if you can help me to fix this. I tried to move it into class and I'm getting error `explicit specialization of 'get' in class scope`. Having outside of the class I'm getting `explicit specialization of 'get' after instantiation`

Comment: @Orion I'm not quite comfortable with function specialization. Search for it or maybe ask another question.

Comment: BTW with your advise I changed the code to this: `std::map<mvs::Code, pair_type> map_ =
        {
            { mvs::Code1, { "Code1", [&](mvs::Code code) { return get<char>(code); } } }
        };`